# Overriding a document keydown listener (from Closure) in a userscript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, userscripts, google-closure

I'm trying to write a userscript to redefine the keybindings of a webapp.  Using the Chrome DOM inspector I've found that the key handler is defined as a keydown event listener on the document object, during the capture phase.  As I understand the event model, any capture-phase listeners on the document object will run before any others, so the only way to get my own listener to run before the default is to install it before the webapp initializes.

So I wrote a userscript with `@run-at document-start` to run

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
  alert("foo");
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, true);
```

before the webapp installs its own handlers.  According to the DOM inspector, my handler is indeed first, and indeed when I hit a key in certain parts of the page, I get the alert.  But within the rich text editor I'm trying to "fix", the alert is entirely missing.

I also tried adding my own replacement `Node.prototype.addEventHandler` to intercept the call that registers the offending handler, but it seems that Closure doesn't fall for it (or else there's some other timing issues), since by the time the page is done loading, it's back to a native function rather than my replacement.  And the native `addEventHandler` apparently makes it impossible to inspect the handlers, so as far as I can tell there's just no way I can get at the webapp's handler to modify or remove it.

So now I've run out of ideas - how would anyone else go about changing this keyhandler?

Comment: rich text editors usually use iframes, so they won't have your scripts that you ran in the parent page.

Comment: Indeed, the event handler is registered on an iframe with src='javascript:""'.  I can access it from my userscript but by the time I can see it, it's already got the bad keyhandler and any handler I can add will go afterwards so it can't prevent the behavior I don't like.